# Impersonation not working in ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I created a web application based on ASP.NET Core 6 with Angular for the frontend. In this web application, I am using Windows Authentication to authenticate the users of the application. This is how the authentication is defined in the IIS settings:
[image: Windows Authentication Configuration IIS]

The authentication itself works fine, but in my application I also need to impersonate the authenticated user in order to perform requests against another REST API (PI Web API).
This is how I am currently trying to do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetSelfUserInfo()
{
    try
    {
        WindowsIdentity user = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
        
        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
        {
            // Create HTTP client instance and perform the request
            PIWebApiClient client = new PIWebApiClient("https://<url>/piwebapi", true);
            PIUserInfo userInfo = client.System.UserInfo();

            return $"IdentityType: {userInfo.IdentityType}\nName: {userInfo.Name}\nIsAuthenticated: {userInfo.IsAuthenticated}\nImpersonationLevel: {userInfo.ImpersonationLevel}";
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return $"Exception during HTTP request: {ex}";
    }
}
```

For some reason, this code does not work as expected. The HTTP request seems to reach the REST API just fine, but the identity of the user does not arrive at the REST API. When I check the Security Eventlogs on the server hosting the REST API, I can see a successful logon (Event ID 4624) but the account name for this logon is `ANONYMOUS LOGON`:
[image: Anonymous login problem]

I already checked via additional debug logging that the current user identity inside the `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated` block is indeed the user which I want to use for performing the request against the REST API.

Why is the user identity getting lost somewhere in this request and what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is anonymous authentication disabled for the REST API, as well? In your question you only mention the settings for your application.

Comment: I'm not sure but could you pls take a try to enable Kerberos in your IIS server? You may use [this tool](https://github.com/SurajDixit/KerberosConfigMgrIIS) to execute the test, and it also provide a revert feature so that if it didn't work, it will also revert all the changing for you. This is [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/surajdixit/kerberos-configuration-manager-for-internet-information-services-server) about how to use it.

Comment: @ChristofWollenhaupt Yes, anonymous authentication is disabled for the REST API.

Comment: @TinyWang Thanks a lot for the link! When I run this application, select "Pass through Kerberos" and click on "Review", it loads for a few seconds and then I get an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Element not found! at KerberosConfigMgr.Kerberos.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)` Any idea, why? Otherwise I'll probably have to debug this application and figure out what's wrong first of all.

Comment: I just compiled the application from the source code myself and executed it. This time, there was no error and the application seems to have found a problem with the ASP.NET Impersonate feature not being enabled. Sadly, even after enabling this feature the authentication is still not working. A HTTP 401 error is returned from the IIS and I have no idea why. It seems like the reason for this is an access denied (code 5) error somewhere in IIS but I don't know where any why.

Comment: Actually I knew little about it, what I knew is that we need to use Kerberos instead of the default NTML when we need to set a credential double hop with windows authentiation in IIS, and I never saw that exception before. You may enable failed request tracing rule for catch 401 error and check the request tracing details, it may tell you if the request contained the credential.

Comment: @TinyWang I was just told that I should not spend any additional time on this topic as it is taking way too long to get this to work. Sorry.